# I want to display the texture as a point cloud like the attached image

Tags: textures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu0Mn.png)I would like to display the texture as a point cloud like the attached image.
For some reason, when I load the textures in pointsMaterial, the textures are white and blurry, so I am loading the textures in shaderMaterial.

I loaded the textures in shaderMaterial and converted them to grayscale. After that, I have no idea what approach to take.